# how to show all records from a specific mySQL row - except duplicates?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, show, rows, except

Is there any easy way to show all records from a specific mySQL row - except the duplicated ones?

Comment: all records from a specific mysql row? Do you mean all records from a specific table?

Comment: There are so many exact duplicates of this question!

Comment: `group by` may also help

Comment: @Flukey yeah need to `SELECT DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct myrow from mytable;
```